# Decode .mov video file with PNG codec type

Tags: ios, macos, avfoundation, video-encoding

I am trying to decode video with "PNG, Timecode" codecs with AVFoundation and get error

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11833 "Cannot Decode" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The decoder required for this media cannot be found.,NSUnderlyingError=0x610000044050 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12906 "(null)"}, AVErrorMediaTypeKey=vide, NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Decode}
```

from AVAssetReader. May be need use specific pixel format type for AVAssetReaderTrackOutput?

Info from videoTrack.formatDescriptions:

```
<CMVideoFormatDescription 0x618000042ac0 [0x7fff7b281390]> {
    mediaType:'vide' 
    mediaSubType:'png ' 
    mediaSpecific: {
        codecType: 'png '       dimensions: 2852 x 1871 
    } 
    extensions: {<CFBasicHash 0x61800006c180 [0x7fff7b281390]>{type = immutable dict, count = 9,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x7fff7eee0750 [0x7fff7b281390]>{contents = "TemporalQuality"} = <CFNumber 0x27 [0x7fff7b281390]>{value = +0, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    1 : <CFString 0x7fff7eee0790 [0x7fff7b281390]>{contents = "Version"} = <CFNumber 0x117 [0x7fff7b281390]>{value = +1, type = kCFNumberSInt16Type}
    2 : <CFString 0x7fff7eee0590 [0x7fff7b281390]>{contents = "FormatName"} = PNG
    3 : <CFString 0x7fff7ad964d8 [0x7fff7b281390]>{contents = "CVPixelAspectRatio"} = <CFBasicHash 0x61800006c140 [0x7fff7b281390]>{type = immutable dict, count = 2,
entries =>
    1 : <CFString 0x7fff7ad964f8 [0x7fff7b281390]>{contents = "HorizontalSpacing"} = <CFNumber 0xb2427 [0x7fff7b281390]>{value = +2852, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    2 : <CFString 0x7fff7ad96518 [0x7fff7b281390]>{contents = "VerticalSpacing"} = <CFNumber 0xb2427 [0x7fff7b281390]>{value = +2852, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}

    4 : <CFString 0x7fff7eee0550 [0x7fff7b281390]>{contents = "VerbatimSampleDescription"} = <CFData 0x618000140370 [0x7fff7b281390]>{length = 106, capacity = 106, bytes = 0x0000006a706e67200000000000000001 ... 00000b2400000000}
    5 : <CFString 0x7fff7eee07b0 [0x7fff7b281390]>{contents = "RevisionLevel"} = <CFNumber 0x117 [0x7fff7b281390]>{value = +1, type = kCFNumberSInt16Type}
    6 : <CFString 0x7fff7eee0770 [0x7fff7b281390]>{contents = "SpatialQuality"} = <CFNumber 0x40027 [0x7fff7b281390]>{value = +1024, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    7 : <CFString 0x7fff7eee07d0 [0x7fff7b281390]>{contents = "Vendor"} = appl
    8 : <CFString 0x7fff7eee05b0 [0x7fff7b281390]>{contents = "Depth"} = <CFNumber 0x2017 [0x7fff7b281390]>{value = +32, type = kCFNumberSInt16Type}
}
}
}
```

Can I decode this video with AVFoundation?

Also if open this video with QuickTime Player and re-save, it saved video with "Apple ProRes 4444, Timecode" codecs and this video can be decoding with AVFoundation, but size of file increase from 800Kb to 2Mb.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can only open H264 encoded video with those APIs.